# Lightning Component - Date formatting not consistent with standard UI

Tags: lightning-aura-components, date, formatting

I am using lightning:datatable to render data including dates.

My date column definition looks like:

```
{ label: 'Expiration', fieldName: 'ExpirationDate__c', type: 'date'}
```

The date in the table is rendered as "Sep 17, 2018".  I even tried rendering it using something like:

```
<ui:outputDate value="{!v.myDataList[0].ExpirationDate__c}"/>
```

... and same results.

Dates rendered from standard SF views (like in related lists for example) look like "09/17/2018"

Why don't my custom components render using the same formatting as standard UI?

Comment: You have to set format attribute of ui:outputDate as 'dd/MM/yyyy:, refer specification- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:outputDate/specification

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the issue I am seeing is related to this: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000FmAgQAK

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `format` attribute to display the output however you want. In your case to be able to display it as `09/17/2018`, you can just have it as:

```
<ui:outputDate value="{!v.myDataList[0].ExpirationDate__c}" format="MM/DD/YYYY"/>
```

Refer to the [documentation's specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:outputDate/specification) for details.

---

If you need to support User's locale, use [lightning:formattedDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedDateTime/documentation) instead, which allows to format the date based on User's locale.

> A lightning:formattedDateTime component displays formatted date and time. This component uses the Intl.DateTimeFormat JavaScript object to format date values. **The locale set in the app's user preferences determines the formatting**.

Comment: But what about different locales?  I should not have to hardcode the format.  If I switch my local to English UK the format should be DD/MM/YYYY.  These are things we don't have to worry about in VisualForce pages.

Comment: If you want to use locale, then you should instead use [**lightning:formattedDateTime**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedDateTime/documentation)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but lightning:formattedDateTime outputs the the same wrong format - "Sep 17, 2018".   Am I the only one seeing this?

Comment: If I specify the format like the following it works but I would expect the default format to match the standard UI's format: <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!v.benefitList[0].ExpirationDate__c}" year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric" />

Comment: Dang, I just noticed that when I use lightning:formattedDateTime the date is rendered 1 day behind the actual date.  Some other thread suggested add timeZone="UTC" to the formatting and that seems to fix it but date formatting in lightning seems all kinds of messed up.  And to confirm, I am outputting a Date object not a DateTime object.

Comment: I haven't really tried much on this, but looking at the documentation it seems there are ways to achieve this.